# angularjs: input tag with conditional type attribute?

Tags: android, angularjs, html, input, android-softkeyboard

As I face an issue related to Android 4.4 Samsung Galaxy TabS regarding the <input type="number"> which does not expose the dot key in the keyboard (hence preventing users to enter decimal values), I need to conditionally set type="text" for such a device, how should I do that as the following does not work?

```
<input type="{{device.isAndroid?'text':'number'}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change input's type dynamically so I would recommend to hardcode both types and use ng-switch or ng-if to show one or the other depending on the device.

for example

```
<input type="text" ng-if="device.isAndroid">
<input type="number" ng-if="!device.isAndroid">
```

or via a directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/0y8I6PIQqot9ZdN6OBnw?p=preview

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function() {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        isAndroid: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

        scope.$watch('isAndroid', function(newValue) {
            if (newValue === true) {
                element.attr('type', 'number')
            } else {
                element.attr('type', 'text')
            }
        })

    }
};
}]);
```

html:

```
<input my-directive is-android="device.isAndroid">
```

Comment: I thought about this but suspecting a better lighter approach. Any chance a directive might help? @rmuller

Comment: check the edit. Not sure if it is the cleanest way to do it, but it is another option that might help you :)

Answer (score 8):

You can change input type with `ng-attr-type`

```
<input ng-attr-type="{{$ctrl.isNumber? 'number' : 'text'}}">
```

P.S. I know its already closed, but I think its useful to have an updated because google search returns this page

Comment: Can't bind to 'ng-attr-type' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: 2021 update: You can now bind directly to the 'type' attribute of an input element in Angular 12. If you're on an earlier version, you can still use 'attr.type'.